# Separating onto a new line based on a delimiter

Tags: shell, awk, delimiter

I have some rows in my file that look like this

```
 ENSG00000003096:E4.2|E5.1
 ENSG00000035115:E14.2|E15.1
 ENSG00000140987:E5.2|ENSG00000140987:E6.1
 ENSG00000154358:E46.1|E47.1
```

I would like to separate them onto a new line based on the delimiter "|" , such that it becomes

```
  ENSG00000003096:E4.2
  ENSG00000003096:E5.1
  ENSG00000035115:E14.2
  ENSG00000035115:E15.1
  ENSG00000140987:E5.2
  ENSG00000140987:E6.1
  ENSG00000154358:E46.1
  ENSG00000154358:E47.1
```

Comment: so, what went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With input data as advised in your question, this seems to work with gnu awk:

```
awk -F: -v RS="[|]|\n" 'NF==1{print p FS $0;next}NF!=1{p=$1}1' file1
#Output
ENSG00000003096:E4.2
ENSG00000003096:E5.1
ENSG00000035115:E14.2
ENSG00000035115:E15.1
ENSG00000140987:E5.2
ENSG00000140987:E6.1
ENSG00000154358:E46.1
ENSG00000154358:E47.1
```

Logic:

`|` or `\n` are used as record separator `RS`
`:` is used as field separator `FS`
If a line has more than one fields then keep the first field in a variable p
if a line has only one field then print previous $1 = variable p and the line $0

Answer (score 0):

You may mean something like

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{ split($2, fields, "|"); print $1 ":" fields[1]; print $1 ":" fields[2]; }' my_file.txt
```